# Put a floating toolbar over a table row

Tags: jquery, css, html-table, css-float, toolbar

I may be missing something obvious but:

I need a little toolbar to show above a row of a table (has to be a table, I'm working with legacy code) when I hover over the row.

One issue is that **tr** does not take *position:relative* (undefined per w3c) so I ended up creating a hidden cell, and putting the toolbar in that, putting the *position:relative* on the **td** ... then messy CSS and some jQuery to reveal the **td** when the row is hovered-over but then there are issues because the HTML engine thinks the newly revealed cell is part of the table and the whole row shifts out.

It's all a bit horrible.

I think I may have to make the **td** visible but of zero width - but I was hoping someone might have a better idea.

Comment: If we could see your code (either on your domain or at jsfeiddle.net) that'd be gret.

Comment: Would an absolutely positioned div be out of the question?

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks meant [jsfiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Pressure of work means I can't spend the time isolating the code (interesting site though) - I'll use a version of the answer below. Thanks for offering to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea would be to have a toolbar made using divs and CSS and have it hidden. Hovering over the row means you are at that very position where you want the toolbar.

Now using the

```
$('#example').mouseover(function(e){
        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
   });
```

I can get the current position where I can show my toolbar. Once the mouse leaves the row, I can hide that toolbar. I hope I understood your question correctly.